# ARM Assembly creating a function

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, arm, raspberry-pi3, nano

The following code is what im having some difficulties with, it takes 3 numbers from the user and adds them up. Although it only returns 1 number no matter the inputs, 135228. I did some research and thought the problem was printf not being able to print ints, but thats not the problem, and I am stuck.

```
.global main
.func main
.data
x: .word 0
y: .word 0
z: .word 0
sum: .word 0
scanPattern: .asciz "%d %d %d"
.balign 4
mes1: .asciz "Enter 3 numbers, separated by spaces"
.balign 4
mes2: .asciz "The sum of the numbers you just entered is %d\n"
.text
main:
push {lr}
ldr r0, =mes1  
bl puts
ldr r0, =scanPattern 
ldr r1, =x
ldr r2, =y
ldr r3, =z
bl scanf

ldr r0, =x
ldr r1, =y
ldr r2, =z
bl summerFunc

ldr r3, =sum
str r0, [r3]
ldr r0, =mes2
ldr r1, =sum
bl printf

pop {lr}
bx lr

summerFunc:
push {lr}
add r0, r0, r1
add r0, r2
pop {lr}
bx lr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ldr r0, =mes2
ldr r1, =sum
bl printf
```

maybe this will help.  mes2 is a string with a %d meaning for this string take the first operand and print that value.  But what you have passed to printf is the ADDRESS to sum not the value sum.  Even though just before that your code showed the understanding that =sum is the address to sum.  (storing the result of the prior function assuming that returns the summation in r0.  r3 = address of sum, write r0 to memory at address of sum. in this case you could just mov r1,r0, then ldr r0,=mes2.  But I suspect your call to the summation function has a pointer vs value problem as well.  dont know what that function looks like though.

if near enough (no doubt here) ldr r1,sum should load the value of sum into r1, where ldr r1,=sum is a syntax trick/shortcut.  assemble then disassemble this code to see what is happening.